# Emulate keypress in webdriver using php

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I have a problem with trigger keypress event in WebDriver with using php. There is element with class > test
On this element bind keypress by jquery . I try to click,but its no result

```
$this->_city = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('test'));
$this->_city->click()
```

Plz, help me, who know how to emulate keypress on webdriwer with using php.

Answer (score 9):

```
$this->_city = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('test'));
$this->_city->click()
$this->driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('TEXT HERE'); // this will insert text in the box
$this->driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER); // This will do a enter or whatever key you like to press ( not letter/numbers move ARROW_UP or whatever you like to presskey)
```

Here are some other keys for the driver:

[Check out more Keys from WebDriverKey](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/WebDriverKeys.php)

[CHECK getKeyboard() Methods](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/1.2.0/Facebook/WebDriver/Remote/RemoteKeyboard.html)

Answer (score 3):

The only one worked for me is **[`WebDriverKeys`](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/WebDriverKeys.php)** :

```
$driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a keypress event, so some type of key on the keyboard being pressed is what you are looking for?  Using the click() event is emulating a mouse click on the element in question.  You will probably want to use the sendKeys() function once the element has focus.

```
$this->_city = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('test'));
$this->_city->click()
$this->_city->sendKeys('A');
```